# How to know if a website is correctly working or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Have just completed developing a WebAPI.

Now, creating an client application for the same.

To do this, I had created a WPF Client application which needs the user to enter the parent URI of the service.

That is,

```
http://localhost:65620/VirtualDirectoryName (Just the base URL not the entire URL)
```

Now, how to check if the URL is correct or not using the client application?

EDIT 1:

**HttpClient can be used**: But I am asking about validating the base URL alone.

Any ideas how to do this ?

(If I put the base address in the Browser, it shows the contents of the Directory. Then I assume  that the installation is correct (At this point I am not calling any methods of webAPI though))

EDIT 2:

**URL is Correct or not**: I have to ensure that the service has been installed correctly in the IIS and it is up and running before any client could access its methods.

Comment: use fiddler and issue get/post/delete etc commands..

Comment: What do you mean by _"URL is correct or not using the client application"_? Define "correct". Explain in words what you expect to happen. Once you've done this, you'll find it's easy to write it in code.

Comment: validate the url alone? `try{ new Url(urlString); } catch (FormatException) { }`

Comment: @Zaki: Yes, but the clients cannot use fiddler. We need to give them a client application.

Comment: how about creating a test service in the webapi, `BaseUri + "\TestApi"` then call the testmethod `public bool Test(){ return true; }`, if it returns successfully then the base uri should be okay?

Comment: @YuliamChandra: Hmm, seems good option. But unfortunately, the development is freezed and cannot add any more methods. Is there any other way ?

Comment: @CodeCaster: Redefined the question. Any ideas ?

Comment: then call an existing method that doesn't require authentication, validation, and return the least result, if any

Comment: @YuliamChandra: Thank you. I think I should go with this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a WebAPI that cannot be modified, and a client application that cannot be modified. You need to call one of the API methods using something, to check the API has been deployed correctly.

Either use the client application to call one of the API's methods.

Or create a test application which calls one of the API's methods.

I may be missing something, but surely there must be a simple GET method in your API that you can call from your test application that would prove the API is running.